# What would be causing a 45sec delay in this asynchronous operation?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

The following code is taking over 45 secs to complete. All I am trying to do is get a single image to display on startup and not reload over time the user comes back to the first UI view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
     dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        // Perform long running process

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI
        });
    });

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSArray *image = @[@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60438364/main.jpg"];

    dispatch_queue_t imageQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Image Queue",NULL);

    for (NSString *urlString in image) {
        dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{

            NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60438364/main.jpg"];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            NSUInteger imageIndex = [image indexOfObject:urlString];
            UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:imageIndex];

            if (image) return;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update the UI
                [image setImage:self.image.image];
            });

        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: even this will not work!

Comment: `code` *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            
            NSUInteger imageIndex = [images indexOfObject:urlString];
            UIImageView *imageVIew = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:imageIndex];
            
            if (!imageVIew) return;
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update the UI
                [imageVIew setImage:image];
            });
            
        }); 
    }}`code`

Comment: `  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            
            NSUInteger imageIndex = [images indexOfObject:urlString];
            UIImageView *imageVIew = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:imageIndex];
            
            if (!imageVIew) return;
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Update the UI
                [imageVIew setImage:image];
            });
            
        }); 
    }}'

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. Update your question with whatever code you need to provide.

Answer (score 2):

This could be the problem:

```
    dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60438364/main.jpg"];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

If `self.image` is something in your interface, that's the issue - you are trying to update the interface on a background thread. That is illegal. Even if it isn't in the interface, you are updating `self` on a background thread, which could be just as problematic.

And if that isn't the problem, this certainly is:

```
    dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{
        // ...
        UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:imageIndex];
```

`self.view` is *definitely* your interface. So you are definitely talking to your interface on a background thread. 
In short, your code is not thread-safe.

Comment: so how would you fix this?

Comment: its taken about 6hours to get this

Comment: of course I'm being down voted for code I'm trying to udrestand

Comment: Move your code where you interact with any `UIImageView` to the area where you grab the main thread. (Move everything after the `NSData *imageData...` to after you grab the main thread again)

Comment: whats confusing to me is the placement not the code